# YouCompleteMe(vim plugin) GoToDefinition doesn't work

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

```
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf='~/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion=1
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf=0
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1 
nnoremap <F5>           :YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gic    :YcmCompleter GoToInclude<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gdc    :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gdf    :YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gip    :YcmCompleter GoToImprecise<CR>
nnoremap <leader>f      :YcmCompleter FixIt<CR>
```

This is the part of `~/.vimrc` related to `ycm`.
Also, `flags` in `.ycm_extra_conf.py` contains the result of `echo | gcc -std=c++11 -v -E -x c++ -` which refers to include paths for `C-family`.

- The problem
  While `auto-complete` works fine, `GoToDefinition` doesn't work at all.
  (Here what `works` means, `ycm` can recognize local header file in projects.)
  According to the [NOTE](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#user-content-the-gotodefinition-subcommand), `GoToDefinition` only works in the current `translation unit`.
  However, `GoToDefinition` only works in the file being edited in my case.
- What I tried: Give up to make `.ycm_extra_conf.py` global

  1. Copy `.ycm_extra_conf.py` into the top of project and modify `g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf` in `~/.vimrc`.
  2. Do `YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics`
  3. Check `final_flags` in `FlagsForFile` function in `.ycm_extra_conf.py` [file](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py).
  4. `final_flags` was like this.
     `['-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '-Wc++98-compat', '-Wno-long-long', '-Wno-variadic-macros', '-fexceptions', '-DN    DEBUG', '-DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER', '-std=c++11', '-x', 'c++', '-isystem', '/home/illuxic/Redbase/../BoostParts', '    -isystem', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers', '-isystem', '/home/illuxic/Redbase/../llvm/inc    lude', '-isystem', '/home/illuxic/Redbase/../llvm/tools/clang/include', '-I', '/home/illuxic/Redbase/.', '-I', '    /home/illuxic/Redbase/./ClangCompleter', '-isystem', '/home/illuxic/Redbase/./tests/gmock/gtest', '-isystem', '/    home/illuxic/Redbase/./tests/gmock/gtest/include', '-isystem', '/home/illuxic/Redbase/./tests/gmock', '-isystem'    , '/home/illuxic/Redbase/./tests/gmock/include', '-isystem', '/usr/include/c++/5', '-isystem', '/usr/include/x86    _64-linux-gnu/c++/5', '-isystem', '/usr/include/c++/5/backward', '-isystem', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/in    clude', '-isystem', '/usr/local/include', '-isystem', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed', '-isystem    ', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '-isystem', '/usr/include']`
  5. `GoToDefinition` still gives me '`RuntimeError: Can't jump to definition.`'

How can I make `GoToDefinition` work?
It can't recognize not only indirectly included header files but also directly included header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the additional details in [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2448).
What I'd misunderstood is in the comment written by @puremourning.
I recommend you to read this comment first.